# Grid not modifying when div size is changed - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a sidebar, that when opened extends to 450px, but because the the size of the window has not changed, the grid isn't updated.

I want to use grid on "Content" as if the size of the window changed, when sidebar is opened - so that grid functionality will be used.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/ztLhpf2g/7/

What to do:

```
<div class="Container container-fluid ">
  <div class="Sidebar"></div>
  <div class="Content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you either show your CSS or apply Bootstrap grid classes to your markup to better illustrate the problem? It'd be great if you could share an example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Grid classes in Bootstap like `col-lg-6, col-md-3, col-xs-12` can react only on window size due to media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

So you cannot make the grid inside `div.Adm-Content-Wrapper` part change only based on its parent size.
You'll have to add additional CSS changing grid in case of opened sidebar, something like this:

```
.Adm-Content-Wrapper.active .row .col-lg-2 {
   width: 100% //put the correct values here
}
```